# Blender bug adding image texture/reference/plane image

Tags: texturing, add-on, image

I´ve been having some problems adding image textures/plane images/reference images/etc to a project.
It was working fine with Blender 2.92, then Blender started to crash. I downloaded Blender 3.0 alpha version and everything seemed to be ok but this morning the same started to happen.
Whenever I try to add an image texture (pressing open) Blender shuts down... Whenever I try to add images as planes Blender crashes.
I have been trying to search online for the cause of this but haven't found anything yet. Can someone help me? Can this be a bug with add-ons? Should I de-select any of the add-ons? Is it something else?
My desktop specs are: Nvidia RTX 1060 6GB, AMD Ryzen 3700x 8-Core CPU, 32GB internal memory...

Please help! :)
Thanks!
Ismael

Comment: You could try staring blender from a terminal with `blender --factory-startup` to see if any of your introduced add-ons are making a difference.

Comment: Hello and welcome. when you say "I uploaded the 3.0 version" do you mean, you are using Blender 3.0?, if so, that's still a Work in progress.Or you mean version 3 of your project?

Comment: I uploaded and am using 3.0 version of Blender. The program also shuts down whenever I try to addd an image texture in the shader editor and also whenever I press the matcap view option or the scene world option the program shuts down.

Comment: As i mentioned before, Blender 3.0 is still on Alpha state, that means that there are a lot of bugs to polish, you could make a bug report [here](https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/)